# Read the current text color in a xterm

Tags: python, bash, xterm

I'm writing various utilities, and I'm really liking colorized text. Nothing fancy, just using escape sequences. I've created a simple class that has a pprint(msg, color) function. I've got it working rather easily after finding the codes [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/terminal_colours/).

The problem that I'm having is that I should be able to turn off the color after printing. For example, let's say a user runs my program that prints almost everything in the default terminal color, but there is an error, and I want to print the error in red. I prefix my error message with '\033[0;32m', and the message is in red. Unfortunately, all text is red until I change it. That's generally fine while my program is running because I know what color the messages should be. However, the color remains after my program ends. Basically, I'd like to read the current color when my program starts, and restore it when finished. The same way that scripts restore the pwd when exiting.

How do I read the current escape sequence?

System:
Red Hat 5.x
Bash
Python 2.3

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible and it's [unlikely to be portable](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions) if it were. The best you can do is send `sgr0` which resets all attributes to default (not previous). On xterms, `sgr0` is `Esc[m`. If you want to reset the colors and not affect other attributes, send `op` which on xterms is `Esc[39;49m`.

These codes should not be hardcoded. You should use terminfo, termcap or [n]curses.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked over the link that you provided, but couldn't find anything relevant to sgr0 or colors. Could you elaborate or provide the section?  Reseting sgr0 seems to work perfectly, and unless there's a compelling portability reason, I'll stick with it in the short-term. Using something that interface with terminfo/termcap or curses directly will be the plan going forward, but it's going to take a while to get those modules added.

Comment: @fandingo: The point of the link is that many terminal emulators that claim to be xterm compatible don't support many of the control sequences that xterm does, thus affecting portability of more obscure capabilities. You can find out more about terminfo in [man 5 terminfo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) and xterm control sequences [here](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).

Answer (score 162):

Rather than using obfuscated escape sequences, use the `tput` facility instead.  Here is an excerpt from my `~/.bashrc` that I use for my PS1 prompt:

```
BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
POWDER_BLUE=$(tput setaf 153)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)
```

To reset the color information such that subsequent text is in the normal terminal color you would append `${NORMAL}` to the end like so:

`echo "${RED}this is red ${NORMAL}this is normal"`

Comment: Useful, but doesn't answer the question as I read it. The user didn't necessarily have the terminal set to the "normal" colour before running the script, and might not want the script to set the "normal" colour afterward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Karl is correct. I need to set it within Python scripts, so while BASH aliases would work, they don't seem to be the best solution. Not that escape sequences are much better...

Comment: Another dependency.. the last thing I need.

Comment: @Dan was that directed at my answer? If so `tput` comes with ncurses, so although it's not a bash built-in, it's pretty much ubiquitous.

Comment: It's not ubiquitous on Windows. I use `.sh` scripts in combination with Git Bash and there are many useful Linux tools that I don't have at my convenience. `tput` is one of them. Sure, I could run cygwin or even just drop a tput executable in my Git directory, but this seems like overkill when the escape sequences work perfectly well. TBH, `$(tput setaf 6)` isn't any less obfuscated than `'\e[00;36m'` to me. They also don't fork another process 15 times while initializing the color constants.

Comment: @Dan we'll you can't please all of the people all the time, 1 out of 18 is pretty good.

Comment: @SiegeX I wasn't your downvote FYI. I appreciate your answer for what it is, these are just my observations. I was frustrated with some other hacky solutions at the time of my initial comment, sorry for that.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it's possible — for
[**xterm**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html), and ***compatible*** terminals.

[xtermcontrol](http://thrysoee.dk/xtermcontrol/) for instance uses the [**`OSC 10`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands) control sequence to retrieve the *default* foreground/background colors.  It's been documented in xterm since 2002.

For other terminals:

- In RHEL 5, the "Terminal" program is gnome-terminal 2.16.0; that version does not recognize **`OSC 10`** (tested with the equivalent CentOS 5).
- The question was asked in 2010, referring to the Red Hat *enterprise* version, which, if anything, is slower to update than Debian.
- Moving forward in time, gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1 on Debian 7 (early 2012) also did not recognize the control sequence.
- Finally, in Debian 8 with 3.14.1 (late 2014) the feature is recognized.
- CentOS 7's gnome-terminal 3.14.3 recognizes the control sequence.

Curious when it was added, bear in mind that VTE's developers don't write documentation. So... studying the git log shows

```
commit 1b8c6b1aac587b79476a60a5830385abc939430d 
Author: Egmont Koblinger <egmont@gmail.com> 
Date:   Wed Jan 22 00:13:51 2014 +0100

    emulation: Add support for OSC 1?1[017] (fg, bg, highlight colors)

    https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=567444
```

On the other hand, the *default* colors are not the same as the *current* colors.  Users have been able to do this with xterm since [patch #93 in 1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_93) using the **`DECRQSS`** control sequence.  That is, putting the terminal into raw mode and doing something like

```
printf '\033P$m\033\\'
```

would get it to reply with the string filled out with the SGR parameters.

If colors were set using SGR, those codes would be part of the reply, e.g.

```
\033P1$r0;33m\033\\
```

to denote foreground color number 3 (encoded as `33`).

You could stop there (because you could extract those parameters and reuse them to set the terminal to the same state later), but then getting the actual RGB colors would be possible using **`OSC 4`**.  You'd use the color number (from the SGR sequence), and send something like this:

```
printf '\033]4;3;?\033\\'
```

So it's certainly doable with xterm.  There'll be a demo/test-script for **`DECRQSS`** in the next update for xterm.

For other programs, you need more time:

- xtermcontrol's developer overlooked **`DECRQSS`** (it has no feature for setting/getting SGR codes).
- VTE's developers copy xterm features in response to bug reports; the VTE source does not mention **`DECRQSS`**.  Its git log mentions **`OSC 4`** in 2009, but the implementation is incomplete (it only allows one to **set** a color, not **get** the color).

Answer (score 4):

```
RED = 31
GREEN = 32
ESCAPE = '%s[' % chr(27)
RESET = '%s0m' % ESCAPE
FORMAT = '1;%dm'

def colorize(text, color):
    return ESCAPE + (FORMAT % (color, )) + text + RESET
```

This function will return a string that will print colorized, with the terminal automatically being reset afterwards.

Comment: There is a problem with the escape sequences. When I print with it, I see the text and all the escape sequences.