# How to get color and width formatting with printf

Tags: bash, printf

I have a simple minimum width format using `printf` like so

```
$ printf "[%-15s][%-10s][%-5s][%-10s]\n" "Hello" "World" "Eat" "Cake"
[Hello          ][World     ][Eat  ][Cake      ]
```

But when I try to add some color to it as per the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413029/15494258), the minimum width formatting goes away

```
$ GREEN=$(tput setaf 2) && printf "[%-15s][%-10s][%-5s][%-10s]\n" "Hello" "World" "Eat" "${GREEN}Cake"
[Hello          ][World     ][Eat  ][Cake]
```

Obviously you can't see on here that it's green, but you can see that the minimum width on the word 'Cake' has dissappeared. What you can't see, but which is also happening, is that the font of the word 'Cake' has changed as well.

**Question:** How can I change the color but keep the minimum width, and if possible, keep the font the same?

Comment: You were right! If you put as an answer I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the `printf` function is counting the escape sequence characters that set the colours as part of the output width. Adding the number of characters required for each colour format to the width specifier should fix the issue.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
$ GREEN=$(tput setaf 2) && printf "[%-15s][%-10s][%-5s][${GREEN}%-10s]\n" "Hello" "World" "Eat" "Cake"
[Hello          ][World     ][Eat  ][Cake      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
printf "[\x1b[34;1m%-15s\x1b[0m][\e[33;1m%-10s\e[0m][\e[31;5m%-5s\e[0m][\e[32m%-10s\e[0m]\n" "Hello" "World" "Eat" "Cake"
```

...works in my bash.

For better handling create a 4 columns format environment variable first for later use...

```
FRMT_BYRG_4COLS='[\x1b[34;1m%-15s\x1b[0m][\e[33;1m%-10s\e[0m][\e[31;5m%-5s\e[0m][\e[32m%-10s\e[0m]\n'
```

...and use it with all what puts out with 4 columns...

```
printf "${FRMT_BYRG_4COLS}" $(ps)
```

( `printf` loops through `$(ps)` 4 columns output )