# Is it possible to get the default background color using curses in python?

Tags: python, colors, curses

Using curses in python you can easily use the default color scheme for the terminal using:

```python
curses.use_default_colors()
```

However once you try to recolor any character, using a color pair you have to declare a background color:

```python
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
```

I really don't want to change the background from the default but I would like to change the foreground.

Is there any way to either get the default background color? or to change just the foreground color?

I am aware that I could use ANSI escape codes to adjust just the foreground color, however ANSI codes are not compatible with curses and I would rather work with curses than rewrite everything in ANSI codes.

Comment: This answers your question: [Read the current text color in a xterm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332478/read-the-current-text-color-in-a-xterm)

Comment: Both suggested answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out,

If you call `init_pair` with `-1` as a value it will fill in the terminal default.  For example to make red text with the default background:

```
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, -1)
```

Now `curses.color_pair(1)` will be set to the background.  This will even work if you change the terminal's default while the program is running.

You do have to call `curses.use_default_colors()` first to use this.

Comment: So you can use -1 to set the foreground/background to the default color, but is it possible to get the *actual color* used for the background? Basically I want to know: is the default background black or blue or white or red or what?

Comment: @dthor I suspect that it is not possible.  Terminals backgrounds don't necessarily need to be a uniform color.

Answer (score 1):

`window.inch(0,0)` will return a value from reading the character at position (0,0) of the window that includes the attributes at that location.  If you use `stdscr` as the window you should get the current colors for the whole screen. Quoting the official documentation:

"Return the character at the given position in the window. The bottom 8 bits are the character proper, and upper bits are the attributes."

```
colors = stdscr.inch(0,0) & curses.A_COLOR
```

should extract the current colors for both foreground and background.  Separating the foreground and background colors is something I am currently trying to figure out myself but haven't had much luck yet.  On a Windows machine the curses implementation is PDCurses, and the source code for PDCurses seems to say that the two colors are combined in the leftmost byte of a 4-byte integer field, but I haven't confirmed that yet.

There is also `window.getbkgd()` which the documentation says will:

"Return the given window’s current background character/attribute pair."

which is more than a little vague.  I am working on nailing down exactly what that function actually returns, though it sounds a lot like the value returned from the `inch` function.

HTH

Peter

[Edit] This sequence of curses calls reliably gives you the foreground and background color numbers.  On *ix systems the defaults are fg=-1 and bg=-1 (-1 means "default" to the init_color() function) but on windows (python 3.8+, windows-curses 2.2.0) the default values are fg=7 (COLOR_WHITE) and bg=0 (COLOR_BLACK).

```
    attr = stdscr.getbkgd()
    stdscr.addstr("scrbkgd={:08X}={}\n".format(attr, attr))
    pair = curses.pair_number(attr)
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        pair = pair >> 16
    fg, bg = curses.pair_content (pair)
    stdscr.addstr("color(scrbkgd) fg={:08X}={},bg={:08X}={}\n".format(fg, fg, bg, bg))
    stdscr.getch()
```